# How to convert exe to video?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, video-conversion, flash, mp4

I have a video with .exe extension. I tried renaming to to mp4, avi, mkv, ts and many more, tried opening it with vlc, none of which worked.

I got the exe when I downloaded a video from a site using [Media Download Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/media-download-helper/bbkghghcepieccnpcneeanmmbhndeblk?hl=en) extension on Chrome.

I tried to open it with winrar using extension `.rar, .zip` didn't work, gave error.

I tried to open the exe but Windows 10 gave error saying that the exe cannot be run, contact the publisher.

How can I convert the file into a vlc playable video?

Note: I have scanned the file with Windows Defender and Mcafee and its safe.

Comment: Just because it scanned safe does not mean it is, delete the file.

Comment: Any video that downloads as an exe is malware.

Comment: Agreed with Moab—this is suspect. I would not trust it at all. It may also be worth submitting to VirusTotal.

Comment: I submitted the file to Virus Total and it came out clean, it might be Adobe Flash. I don't know much about it though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you **sure** it's really a video file? The fact that Download Helper downloaded it doesn't guarantee anything - Download Helper might not recognize the path to the actual video file properly, or the website author might have tricked it purposefully into downloading a wrong file.

If nothing can open it, even after renaming to different extensions, then it's probably not a video file.

Too bad that you already tried to run it. You can never be sure whether the message that the executable can't be run was a genuine Windows message, or it was a fake message displayed by very this .exe program while it was doing something in the background - and you don't know what...

Try to submit the file you have to a website of some antivirus/anti-malware company for analyzing.

Comment: I submitted the file to Virus Total and it came out clean, it might be Adobe Flash. I don't know much about it though.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the site where you downloaded it from?

Comment: I cannot, but it's an educational website which has courses.

Comment: So the .exe file you downloaded may be a player specific to this website, which gets the actual content from their server and plays it to you.